# postgresql looking for wrong column name

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Developing a Spring application backed by a postgresql database.

Was experiencing a wild issue and had to rebuild the database. This seemed to work on develop, but did not work on my production hosted database.

When attempting to retrieve entities, it's looking for a column that doesn't exist and whose entity does not define it. It looks like it's looking for very old code that doesn't exist anymore and was problematic for postgres to handle in the first place.

Here's what I'm getting

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column harvestite0_.name does not exist`

here's the entity in reference

```
@Entity
public class HarvestItem {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private Integer hType;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @JsonManagedReference(value = "harvest-item-inventory-items")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "harvestItem", targetEntity = InventoryItem.class)
    private List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems;

    // Autogen Get-Set


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<InventoryItem> getInventoryItems() {
        return inventoryItems;
    }

    public void setInventoryItems(List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems) {
        this.inventoryItems = inventoryItems;
    }

    public Integer gethType() {
        return hType;
    }

    public void sethType(Integer hType) {
        this.hType = hType;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

and here is the repository for the harvest item entity

```
package harvest.repositories;

import harvest.entities.HarvestItem;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface HarvestItemRepository extends CrudRepository<HarvestItem, Integer> {
    List<HarvestItem> findByTitle(String title);
}
```

Comment: maybe u have public getter  in ur HarvestItem  class and jpa try to fill that field  and dose not exsist

Comment: When exactly does the error pop up, could you provide more context? Are you sure you're trying to deploy the up-to-date version? Do you use any database change management tool?